# #error command invoke error

Tags: c, debugging, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run and debug C code in Tux Racer source code for Android. Most of a code is written in C, so I converted Android project into C Project (Adds C/C++ Nature). I used Cygwin toolchain.
Now I have problem because Eclipse is finding some imaginary errors in code, like:

```
#if defined( HAVE_SDL )
#   include "SDL.h"
#elif defined( HAVE_GLUT )
#   include "GL/glut.h"
#elif defined( __APPLE__ )

#else

# error "Neither SDL nor GLUT are present."

#endif
```

, where he sees `#error "error text"` as an error. But not everywhere! Only in this place in code. If I shift this line somewhere else, then it's fine. But, this should in any case stay where it is.

Before, I used to just rebuild C code from Cygwin console, and then run from Eclipse Android app, and it worked fine.

Comment: Where is this `HAVE_SDL` defined?

Comment: Nowhere. There is no definition for SDL. Souce for Tux is here [Tux on GitHub](https://github.com/drodin/TuxRider)

Comment: Is your project building in Eclipse? I think you must check that in some files you have got either of the macros `HAVE_SDL`, `HAVE_GLUT` or `__APPLE__` and maybe in some files you have not. It looks like that. I would suggest you to have a look into `Project Settings -> C/C++ Build -> Settings` and also `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols`

Comment: `HAVE_*` macros are usually defined in `config.h` which in turn is created when you run `./configure`. Ensure that `config.h` exists and has the proper macros defined.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Eclipse is that he presumes a lot of things. He didn't used NDK and existing make file, but started using his own settings.
To make it build properly, I needed to change some settings:

1. In Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Builder Settings tab: Use
   default build command should be unchecked; build comand should be
   `bach <path to NDK>ndk-build`. Also, Generate makefile automatically should also be
   unchecked. Then, a proper Build directory should be typed in. That
   is all for Builder Settings tab.
2. Then, Build 'Debug' for project should be checked
3. CTRL+B, and it works!

Almost! It still have some error problems and is left is to figure out how to connect it, run it and debug it on Android from Eclipse.